# Hibernate Envers auditing - 'delete' not audited, after 'add' numerous 'edit' records are added

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

we have a an entity ('Something'), with a ManyToOne mapping to a 'ListOfSomething' and 'SomethingSource'.
we've marked the ManyToOne associated fields with @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED).

after deleting an entity, no records are created in the Something_Aud table.
after adding an entity - a number of records are added to the Something_Aud table: a single 'add' record, and as many 'edit' records as the number of entities in the matching ListOfSomething.

what are we doing wrong?
will provide more information gladly if required.

Comment: There's definitely sth wrong :). Shouldn't work that way. What's your setup? What kind of container, which Hibernate version, transactions etc?

Comment: unfortunately my colleague decided to solve this by manual auditing (instead of relying on hibernate), so it'll take me a while to find the time to re-create the issue in order to find a solution... sorry.

Comment: Is this still a problem @YonatanKarni?

Comment: I'm ashamed to say I never took the time to revisit this...